# How to start using Slug URLs without breaking old in Yii2

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2, slug

i want to rewrite my URLs from

```
/view?id=100
```

to

```
/view/100-article-title
```

But the site already has several thousand search pages. As far as I know, such a change can be bad for SEO. Is there a way to keep the old URLs working when switching to the new routing.

*I am creating links as follows:

```
Url::to(['view', 'id' => $item->id])
```

Is it possible to create links further through ID?

Comment: The old URLs should still work unless you configure `enableStrictParsing` to `true`. Did you try it?

Comment: @RaulSauco no, I just started studying this topic. Where is this parameter set?

Comment: @daniilsidorov refer [Yii2 Routing and URL Creation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing)

Comment: In the application configuration, if you didn't set it to `true` it will be `false` by default, so, by default, you should be getting the behavior that you want. Give that a try and, if you find that something is not working, update your question with the details. Have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

you can create getLink() function on your model and use it on. Then, when function runs you can check id if id <= 100 then return Url::to(['view', 'id' => $item->id]) else return Url::to(['view', 'id' => $item->id, 'slug' => $this->slug])

And add route with slug on your main.php

Answer (score 0):

Look at my example.

First config urlManager in config.php in 'app/config' folder. In my case look like:

```
 'components' => [
    ...
    'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules' => [
                    ''=>'home/index',
                    '<slugm>-<id:\d+>-' => 'home/view',

                ],
            ],
    .
    ...
],
```

and create link as fallow:

```
Url::to(['/home/view', 'id' => $model->home_id, 'slugm' =>$model->title_sr_latn])
```

and finaly url look like:

https://primer.izrada-sajta.rs/usluge-izrade-sajtova-1-